# Is there a way to save apps's positions in mission control's spaces for rebooting

Tags: big-sur, mission-control

When I reboot, my apps stick together on the first space, when before rebooting, they were on different spaces.

Comment: Are these "real" manually-created Spaces, or automatic fullscreen Spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving your app's window to a space (or opening it on a space), right-click on the app's icon in the dock and select `Options > (Assign to) This Desktop`. This makes the app always open on that space, also after reboot.

Comment: I only have options keep in dock, open at login and show in finder.

Comment: Do you have multiple spaces open when you do that?

Comment: They open in their own spaces (fullscreen).

Comment: Fullscreen Spaces are not "real" Spaces so you cannot tie any app to one like you can with 'proper' Spaces. tbh, I don't know how they should behave after reboot, as I never use them, because of the above.